# Rails Webpacker not finding modules (just upgraded to ROR 6.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I've just upgraded to ROR 6.1 from 5.4 and have had to start using Webpacker (just used Sprockets before). I've been through the Rails upgrade wizard and installed up-to-date packages through yarn, but can't get Webpacker working.
Whenever I run 'bin/webpack-dev-server', I get multiple error messages for each module saying this:

```
   ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@rails/activestorage' in '/Users/oli/pre_product/app/javascript/packs'
resolve '@rails/activestorage' in '/Users/oli/xxx/app/javascript/packs'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/oli/xxx/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration....
```

Then when I run the app locally(through NGROK), I see Webpacker requesting a file in 'public/packs/js' that doesn't exist. There's other compiled files, but none with the correct name.

It seems like Webpacker is looking in the wrong place for modules, but everything in the webpacker.yml file seems fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oli

---

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "@rails/webpackerj": "^6.0.0-pre.1",
    "@shopify/app-bridge": "^1.28.0",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-utils": "^1.28.0",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^5.12.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.4-4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "non-digest-webpack-plugin": "0.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

webpacker.yml:

```
    # Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

group :production do
  # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
  gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
end

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.0'
gem "clearance" 
gem 'spec', '~> 5.3', '>= 5.3.4'
gem 'rspec'

gem 'webpacker'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'chart-js-rails', '~> 0.1.6'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'chartjs-ror'
gem 'inline_svg'
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1.6'
gem 'liquid'


# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
#gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
   # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
   gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
   gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'webdrivers'
end



# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'rake'
gem 'shopify_app', '~> 15.0'
gem 'shopify_api', '~> 9.0'

gem 'httparty'
#for CORS, i.e. external domain requests via the api controller
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'whenever', require: false
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
// To reference this file, add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> to the appropriate
// layout file, like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')


require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery");


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
require("shopify_app")
```

Answer (score 1):

run `yarn add @rails/activestorage`

It resolves this error